# the app does not display pictures in file.html - Django, Python

Tags: python, django, image

I have problem with inserting photos to my file.html in django-app. I tried to make many changes, but the picture is still not displayed. I will be grateful for any help.

**My html file**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<h2>Home templates</h2>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
{% for frond_photo in frond_photo_list %}
{% if frond_photo.image %}
<img src="{{frond_photo.image.url}}" class="img-responsive" />
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def frond_photo_list(request):
    queryset = Frond_Photo.objects.all()
    context = {
        "photos": queryset,
    }
    return render (request, "reviews/home.html", context)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Frond_Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**urls.py (app)**

```
...
url(r'^home/', views.frond_photo_list, name='home'),
...
```

**admin.py**

```
class Frond_PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Frond_Photo
admin.site.register(Frond_Photo)
```

When my file looks like this (below) Everything is working properly. The pictures are displayed and I can adapt them to my needs. I think I had to forget something simple ...

**models.py**

```
class Wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)


    def average_rating(self):
        all_ratings = [list(map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all()))]
        return np.mean(all_ratings)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def wine_list(request):
    wine_list = Wine.objects.order_by('-name')
    context = {'wine_list':wine_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_list.html', context)
```

**.html**

```
...
{% if wine_list %}
{% for wine in wine_list %}
{% if wine.image %}
<img class="thumbnail"  src="{{wine.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap"  style="width:100%" width="100" height="250" >
{% endif %}
...
```

**EDIT Stettings.py**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'reviews',
    'registration'
]

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 # One-week activation window
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True # Automatically log the user in.



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'winerama.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'winerama.wsgi.application'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/reviews/review/user'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'reviews/media')
```

Comment: `{% for frond_photo in frond_photo_list %}` --> `{% for frond_photo in photos %}`

Comment: hey can you post your setting file, please chekc have you added the  MEDIA settinngs or not

Comment: Media file is added. {% for frond_photo in frond_photo_list %}->{% for frond_photo in photos % ->
thank you very much!

Comment: @MaddieGraham Because in your context you name that list as `photos`: 
    `context = {"photos": queryset,}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context you set the queryset to the name `photos` but in the template you're attempting to loop through `frond_photo_list`.
If you change the for-loop line in your template to:

```
{% for frond_photo in photos %}
```

you should get the result you want.